# How to connect with Ubuntu 18.04 to WPA3?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, wpa-supplicant, wpa3

After researching and not coming to a solution or idea, I am going to ask the community here.

Is it possible to upgrade packages in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to connect with NetworkManager from the GUI to WPA3 protected networks, and if so, what packages or what config is to set up?

I'm curious for your answers.

Comment: Hi wpa3 network setup is done by you?

Comment: You need NetworkManager 1.16 or newer

Answer (score 0):

As @adasiko said, You need NetworkManager 1.16+
https://blogs.gnome.org/lkundrak/2019/03/15/networkmanager-1-16/

This version is available first in Ubuntu 19.04 Disco:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/net/network-manager

The easiest way to get it is probably to upgrade to that release.  However, I don't see WPA 3 in the drop-down in the GUI in that release, so this still isn't a great answer.